# How to convert timestamp from #event.timestamp to readable date

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-directive

I tried capturing event time in my directive - with $event.timestamp inside @HostListener in angular6. But it shows some like 242035.1050000172. How do i convert it into readable date

Comment: Isnt it supposed to be a normal timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

```
{{$event.timestamp | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

Comment: I tried this, this gives some different date from 1970, sometimes 1969

Comment: Please post the code you have tried, and the variable name you are trying to use.